# Free Vector Space of product space is isomorphic to tensor product of free spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $S$ and $T$ be two arbitrary sets and consider the free vector space $C(S)$ and $C(T)$ generated respectively by $S$ and $T$. Show that $C(S \times T)$ is isomorphic to $C(S) \otimes C(T)$.

I know that in this link: [$C(S \times T)$ is isomorphic to $C(S) \otimes C(T).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753585/cs-times-t-is-isomorphic-to-cs-otimes-ct) there is an answer to this question. But I want to solve the problem in a different way.

My approach is: I want to construct a bilinear map $\varphi:C(S) \times C(T) \rightarrow C(S) \otimes C(T)$ and then by the universal property exists a linear map $ f: C(S) \otimes C(T) \rightarrow C(S \times T) $ such that $\varphi = f \circ \otimes$ and i want $f$ to be bijection.
So, i think that $\varphi(s,t) = (s,t)$ and $f(s \otimes t) = (s,t) $ but i think that these maps does not work.

Any Suggestion?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You must assume that in $C(S \times T)$, $\lambda \times (s,t) = (\lambda s,t) = (s,\lambda t)$ and $(s,t) + (s,t') = (s,t+t')$ because this is true in $C(S) \otimes C(T)$ ? Does this happen in $C(S \times T)$ ? I think not ?

Comment: @Balajisb Hello! I don't know, if we assume that the problem is done, right? But I think we cannot assume this

Comment: Then one way to argue to resolve this problem is that $(s,t+t')$ and $(\lambda s,t)$ and $(s,\lambda t)$ does not even belong to $C( S \times T)$. In otherwords in every equivalence class corresponding to $s \otimes t$ only one element is present in $C(S \times T)$. This must be the way to prove this mapping is a bijection.